# Checking for file on remote computer's desktops

Tags: powershell, path, remote-access, desktop

I'm trying to run a loop that checks a list of computers for a particular access database on the desktop.  I've got it to work when checking in a path such as Users\Default, but really I need it to check on the **desktop of the user that's currently logged in**.  Is this possible or would I need a list of particular usernames to go along with the .txt of computer names?

```
$computers=Get-Content C:\Users\zrasner\Documents\project_files\powershell_computernames\computernames.txt

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    $path = Test-Path "\\$computer\c$\Users\Default\VAST.accdb\"
    If ($path -eq $true) { Write-Host "($computer) VAST is present in Default Users Folder"}
    If ($path -eq $False) { Write-Host "($computer)VAST File Not Found"}
}
```

Again, I'd like to change the check destination to be the desktop of the remote computer in question.

Comment: You will need to remove the final backslash here `Test-Path "\\$computer\c$\Users\Default\VAST.accdb\"` This is currently looking for a folder called 'VAST.accdb' not a file. To check for a file on the desktop you'd need to use `Test-Path "\\$computer\c$\Users\Default\Desktop\VAST.accdb"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `$user` line in the code below gets the user name. The `$user = ($user).Split('\')[-1]` line splits by backslash and returns the last section of the split. This means it will capture the user name from domain\username or username.

```
$computers=Get-Content C:\Users\zrasner\Documents\project_files\powershell_computernames\computernames.txt

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    $path = $false

    $user = Get-WmiObject –ComputerName $computer –Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserName
    $user = ($user).Split('\')[-1]

    $path = Test-Path "\\$computer\c$\Users\Default\VAST.accdb"
    If ($path) { Write-Host "($computer) VAST is present in Default Users Folder"}

    $path = Test-Path "\\$computer\c$\Users\$user\VAST.accdb"
    If ($path) { Write-Host "($computer) VAST is present in currently logged on user ($user)'s Folder"}

    If ($path -eq $False) { Write-Host "($computer)VAST File Not Found"}
}
```

Comment: Your code won't work correctly as it is looking for a folder called 'VAST.accdb' not a file. You need to remove the trailing backslash from each `Test-Path` as this signifies that the path is a folder.

Comment: My bad, @JamesC. Thanks - copied & pasted the users code without removing the slashes - sorted in the edit.